# Why do I have to keep exporting my $PATH for php5?

Tags: php, path, export, laravel-artisan

I noticed this problem when I was using laravel locally. I would run `artisan serve` and encounter an error when something wasn't parsed.

I realized after some time that re-downloading php5 was not the issue and that all I needed to do was `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` and things would work again.

The issue is that I have to do this every so often. I don't understand why. Why do I keep having to do this? Why is it changing?

Comment: Put it in your `.bash_profile` so that it runs every time you start the terminal. Or did you try that?

Comment: but isn't that what exporting it does or is that only temporary? Please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Only temporery. PATH is just an environment variable.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.